# again.... bash version mac didn't change

Tags: bash, macos, brew

On MacOS I installed `bash` with:

```
brew install bash
```

That created `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.18/bin/bash`

The command `which -a bash` reports only `/bin/bash`.  If I close the terminal, reboot, etc. I see the same output.

I added the new bash to `/etc/private/shells`, then changed my default shell to the new version of `bash`:

```
sudo vim /private/etc/shells # added new bash 5.0.18 path
chsh -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.18/bin/bash
```

Then I rebooted, but I still see:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What command did you run to see the 3.2.57 version?  Simply `bash --version`?  What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` say?

Comment: Yep, I used 'bash --version'... right now seems like all working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`brew` installs `bash` in `/usr/local/bin` so that is what you want to add to `$PATH` otherwise you'll have to update `$PATH` every time `bash` is updated.

Did you also want to make that bash your login shell? Then:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Comment: then I'm run brew install bash it's by default install it to /usr/local/Cellar/....
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash yep, ofc I tried that

Comment: Don't forget that the questioner was _also_ not checking the version correctly.

Comment: Yes, it installs in /usr/local/Cellar... but you will find that the brew formula creates a soft link in /usr/local/bin that points to the Cellar:  `ls -l /usr/local/bin/bash
lrwxr-xr-x 1 richard admin 30 2020-07-12 00:30 bash -> ../Cellar/bash/5.0.18/bin/bash`